# Validating an optional Field With React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forms

I'm working on a form with some optional fields that need to be validated only if an input is entered. However, react hook form returns a validation error even when no inputs. I have also tried to set:

```
required: {
value: false,
message: "This field is not required"
}
```

#### But it still returns a validation error even when no inputs are entered.

Below is the code snippets for one of the fields that need to be validated only if an input is entered.

```
<div className={styles.formInputFile}>
          <label htmlFor="ref_letter">
            Reference Letter (For Doctorate and Diploma Courses)
          </label>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name={"reference_letter"}
            rules={{
            required: {
              value: refLetterRequired();
              message: "This is field is required",
},
              validate: {
                fileSize: (file) => {
                  return (
                    file?.size < 2000100 &&
                    "File size shouldn't be more than 2MB!"
                  );
                },
                acceptedFormats: (file) => {
                  return (
                    ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf"].includes(
                      file?.type
                    ) || "Only JPEG, PNG and PDF files are accepted!"
                  );
                },
              },
            }}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange, ...field } }) => {
              return (
                <input
                  {...field}
                  value={value?.fileName}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    onChange(event.target.files[0]);
                  }}
                  type="file"
                  id="rererence_letter"
                  accept=".png, .jpeg, .pdf"
                />
              );
            }}
          />
          <p>{errors.reference_letter?.message}</p>
        </div>
```

#### Second Edit:

The form is a multi-step form and each step needs to be free of errors before users can move to the next step. Below are all the code snippets controlling the field. I keep getting validation errors even when the right inputs are there and when the field is not required.

```
  const certCourses = [
    "Certificate in D",
    "Certificate in t",
    "certificate in H",
    "Certificate in P",
    "Certificate in Pus",
    "Certificate Hec Diseases",
    "Certificate in He",
  ];

  const refLetterRequired = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < certCourses.length; i++) {
      if (watch("proposed_course") === certCourses[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

Expectations. If the "proposed_course" selected is not in "certCourses", then the field should be required, otherwise, the field should not be required.

##### Code controlling "next" button of the multi-step form:

```
  const next = async (e) => {
    const field = steps[currentStep].fields;
    const output = await trigger(field);
    if (!output) return;
    setValue(e.target.name, e.target.value, {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldValidate: true,
      shouldTouch: true,
    });
    setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
  };

const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);




const steps = [
  {
    name: "step 1",
    description: "Personal Information",
    fields: [
      "title",
      "surname",
      "first_name",
      "gender",
      "middle_name",
      "maiden_name",
      "religion",
      "birth_date",
      "nationality",
      "state_of_origin",
      "disability",
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "step 2",
    description: "Next of Kin Information",
    fields: [
      "next_of_kin_name",
      "next_of_kin_address",
      "next_of_kin_relationship",
      "next_of_kin_phone",
      "next_of_kin_occupation",
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: `file?.size < 2000100` should be `>`

Comment: `file?.size < 2000100` is the right expression if we want users not to upload more than 2 MB. If we want them to upload at least 2MB of file, then we use `file?.size > 2000100`. In my case, I want users not to upload more than 2MB of files.

Comment: So it should be `&&` and not `||`. Otherwise, it will always return either `true` or `File size shouldn't be more than 2MB!` and will be treaded as error

Comment: I just changed ||  to && and the problem persists. what else do you suggest, please?

Comment: I have posted the edited code with a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the field value is empty or equal to the default value and return "true"(i.e. indicate that the field passed validation) in that case.
For example

```
fileSize: (file) => {
  if (file === null) return true;
  return (
    file?.size < 2000100 &&
    "File size shouldn't be more than 2MB!"
   );
},
```

There is a closed issue about this in the react-hook-form github https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1781

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired functionality by using watch and setting conditional rules. here is a basic example of doing this, copy this and try it out in a sandbox, it only requires the second input when the first input is given.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type FieldInputs = {
  requiredInput: string;
  optionalInput: string;
};

export const WatchExample = () => {

  const { watch, register } = useForm<FieldInputs>();
  const HasInput = watch("requiredInput");

  return (
    <div>
      <input {...register("requiredInput", { required: true })} />
      <input
        type="text"
        {...register("optionalInput", {
          required: HasInput?.length > 1 ? true : false,
        })}
      />
      {HasInput?.length > 1 && <div>Only show when input is given </div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: But what if optional input has custom validation rules, as in the question? Validate function will be executed on its own without depending on other validation rules included in the required attribute. https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register

Comment: @BatemirKaruev I think this is exactly my case.

Comment: @Kyle Xyian Dilbeck Thanks for the solution you provided. However, I think my case is a bit specific. Please help check the second edit I posted all the associated code. I still getting validation errors even if the field is not required. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @MuhammedAboo_Anas have you tried the solution i suggested? Maybe you should check `if (file === undefined) return true` instead of `null`

Comment: @BatemirKaruev Yes I have tried your solution and it gave me weird behaviour. It still triggered the validation error even when "proposed_course" selected is in certCourses list.  Using || triggered the validate error but continues to the next step if the correct input is provided. However, using && triggered the validate error and didn't continue to the next step even after the correct input was given. I didn't expect the validate error at all after having `if(file=== undefined) return true;` in the function.

Comment: @BatemirKaruev Your solution later worked after deleting my build folder and rebuilding the app Thanks a lot